# Nuxt3 - runtimeConfig not working in Layout

Tags: nuxt.js

My `nuxt.config.ts` has

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      API_BASE_URL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
    },
  },
});
```

and inside my `layouts/default.vue`

```
export default {
    setup() {
        const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();
        return { runtimeConfig }
    }
}
```

with my `.env` file that consist API_BASE_URL

In `pages/files` i can call `this.runtimeConfig.public.API_BASE_URL` to get the data, but inside `layout/default.vue`, is `undefined`. Any ways to overcome this issue ?

Comment: In theory, this condition should not occur. In my past experience, I have not encountered any problems with it. Can you provide more information?